# Kafka not a member of package error in spark app with kafka consumer

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-kafka

#### 1.My Code:

this is my source code:

```
package com.example.day01

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.{ConsumerStrategies, KafkaUtils}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

object SparkOnKafkExample extends App {
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]")
    .setAppName("SparkOnKafka"), Seconds(2))

  // checkpoint
  ssc.checkpoint("hdfs://cdh1.macro.com/data/spark-check-point")


  // kafka配置
  val kafka_config: Map[String, Object] = Map[String, Object](
    "bootstrap.servers" -> "10.168.1.39:9092"
    , "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer] // 指定序列化的方式
    , "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer] // 指定反序列化方式
    , "group.id" -> "group01"
    // 指定消费位置
    //
    , "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest"
    // 提交方式  true ：自动提交
    , "enable.auto.commit" -> (true: java.lang.Boolean)
  )

  // topics
  val topic: Array[String] = Array("spark-example-topic")

  // 配置消费
  val streams: InputDStream[ConsumerRecord[String, String]] = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
    ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe(topic, kafka_config))

  // wordcount
  streams.map(_.value()).flatMap(line => line.split("\\s")).map((_, 1))
    .updateStateByKey((values, state: Option[Int]) => {
      Some(values.sum + state.getOrElse(0))
    }).print()

  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
}
```

maven

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                            </args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.example.dao.KTV</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

#### 2.ERROR INFO

when i run this example, the compiler prompts me:

```
Error:(3, 19) object kafka is not a member of package org.apache
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
Error:(4, 19) object kafka is not a member of package org.apache
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
Error:(7, 35) object kafka010 is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.{ConsumerStrategies, KafkaUtils}
```

#### 3.What did I do

1. i invalid and restart IDEA
2. disable scala plugins,and next install it.
3. Re import dependencies repeatedly

But... still ERROR...
I don't think it's problem with my code.
Have you ever had this problem? How to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Do you use Maven, SBT or something else to add libraries to your project? Or you use Intellij defined libraries directly?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I use Maven to add and manage dependencies.I added Maven dependency to my problem description.

Comment: If you run "mvn install" command in your project , does it complete successfully?

Answer (score 0):

> kafka is not a member of package org.apache

You should remove `kafka-clients` as a dependency since it conflicts with Spark's Kafka Integration

> object kafka010 is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming

You've declared only `spark-sql-kafka-0-10` (which depends on `spark-core` + `spark-sql`), and not `spark-streaming-kafka` (which is deprecated and [where `KafkaUtils` comes from, and is not under a `kafka010` package](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html))

[Refer docs for how to consume from Kafka with Spark Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)